# How to convert FirefoxWebElememt into string type?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm getting the following error while executing my Python program which tries to add the href elements to base URL to form the URL of next page :

"TypeError : cannot concatenate 'str' and 'FirefoxWebElement' object "

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
my_url = 'http://cbseaff.nic.in/cbse_aff/schdir_Report/userview.aspx'
browser.get(my_url)

radio_key_word = browser.find_element_by_id("optlist_0")
radio_key_word.click()

time.sleep(6)

search = browser.find_element_by_id('keytext')
search.send_keys('0')
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

search.clear()
time.sleep(6)

initial_url = 'http://cbseaff.nic.in/cbse_aff/schdir_Report/'

# links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr/td/a/@href')
links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr/td/a/@href")

print len(links)

for link in links:
    # print str(link)
    new_url = initial_url + link
    print new_url

browser.close()
```

This is the error i'm getting while executing:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Python_project/8_March_2017/test_subject.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
25
  File "C:/Python_project/8_March_2017/test_subject.py", line 30, in <module>
    new_url = initial_url + link
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'FirefoxWebElement' objects
```

Comment: You definitely need to provide more info, including the HTML you are executing against and what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: i have updated the question can you check it now ?

Answer (score 2):

The error you get is not a selenium error. But rather a simply python string concatenation with an non-string object. `find_elements_by_xpath` gives you list of WebElement object while `<web_element>.get_attribute("attribute")` gives you string object.

Since you want to get the href instead of the text, you could try grab the attribute instead.

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div/tr/td/a')
for link in links:
    new_url = base_url + link.get_attribute("href")
```

Reference: [selenium.WebElement.get_attribute](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute)

Comment: on making the changes as mentioned i get a new error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python_project/8_March_2017/test_subject.py", line 28, in <module>
    for link in links.get_attribute("href"):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute' `

Comment: Apologize, i forget to mentioned that `get_attribute` is for WebElement object, whereas the find_elements give you list of WebElement. So i've update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I managed to correct the code to get the 'href' in correct format. Thanks to Yeo. Below is my code for the same changes which i made.

```
 link = browser.find_element_by_id(test1).get_attribute("href")
 print link
```

now i'm able to get the correct output:

```
http://cbseaff.nic.in/cbse_aff/schdir_Report/AppViewdir.aspx?affno=930305
http://cbseaff.nic.in/cbse_aff/schdir_Report/AppViewdir.aspx?affno=530382
```